# How can I debug Xamarin code while running a Xamarin.UITest using NUnit

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

Using Visual Studio 2017 (NUnit 2 Test Adapter plugin) / Nunit / Xamarin.UITest:

How can I hit a breakpoint in a dll used by the android app
while running a Test using Xamarin.UITest

So this is the scenario:
App.UITest [Test] <- App.Android -> calling a service in a dll (set breakpoint)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to set these in your VS 2017? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/project-settings-for-csharp-debug-configurations?view=vs-2019

Comment: Yes I Can, but I do not see how this can help in solving my 'problem' ? Or what options do I have to set in order to get this working..